# Can't start the Apache server, php5_module error

Tags: php, apache

I am not an expert (and do not want to be), just trying to install Apache server on my computer so I can test locally a Presta Shop theme I am creating. I followed [this guide](https://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Manual_install_on_Windows_7_with_Apache_and_MySQL) to install all the required stuff, however when I get to the "httpd -k start" I get an error: "can't locate api module structure php5_module'" Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Check this lines are correct for where you installed PHP `LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll"`

Comment: I just checked, the file is there

Comment: You didnt tell us you have installed PHP7?